# Showing error when trying to create pop in transition

Tags: .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and am trying to create a simple pop in effect. But I get the following error "The attachable property Triggers was not found in type newwindow. Below is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.newwindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="newwindow" Height="295" Width="371">
<Grid Height="257" Width="349">
    <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,0,0,112" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="127" />
    <newwindow.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="newwindow.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </newwindow.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am using VS 2010 with .net 3.5 framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace newwindow.Triggers through Window.Triggers and newwindow.Loaded through Window.Loaded.

The programm knows that you want to refer to your newwindow because its in the xaml of your newwindow-Window (And consider renaming your "newwindow")^^.

(You could have edited your old Question...)

Comment: Sorry but doesnt work. Shows the following error "the attachable property Triggers was not found in type Window".

Comment: And place it outside the Grid (e.g. directly under <Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.newwindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="newwindow" Height="295" Width="371"> )